# Strange behavour of file.write command

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is a piece from a larger code. I see strange behaviour from the ofile.write command.

```
def buildruleset(sl, irf, orf):
    for a, b, c in sl:
        with open(irf, 'r') as ifile, open(orf, 'a') as ofile:
            for k in ifile:
                eachk = k.split('\t')
                if a in eachk[7] or a in eachk[8]:
                    print(k)  # This is just for validation
                    ofile.write(k)
```

The results that i see in the file (as a result of ofile.write command) is below:

> 10.190.40.48_29;MMS_10.190.40.45;SYS002_10.32.2.10;FKC_10.32.2.21 ;;DREAM_SKEW    ;;snmp;snmp-trap;echo-reply;icmp-requests;udp_traceroute    Log DREAM_SKEW  Any 
>   NEW RULE:SNMP Rules;   12 security_rule       SNMP RULES  SKEW SNMP RULE
>     false   accept  ;;ss01_10.32.2.20;SS02_10.32.2.61;SYS002_10.32.2.10;FKC_10.32.2.21  ;;SKEW_DMZ_10.41.7.0_24;SKEW_10.41.6.240_29 ;;snmp;snmp-trap;echo-reply;echo-request    Log DREAM_SKEW  Any 
>   NEW RULE:

The results that i see on screen (as a result of the print command) is below:

> **11  security_rule       SNMP RULES  SKEW SNMP RULE  false   accept  ;;ss01_10.32.2.20;SS02_10.32.2.61;MMS_**10.190.40.48_29;MMS_10.190.40.45;SYS002_10.32.2.10;FKC_10.32.2.21   ;;DREAM_SKEW    ;;snmp;snmp-trap;echo-reply;icmp-requests;udp_traceroute    Log DREAM_SKEW  Any 
>   NEW RULE:SNMP Rules;   12 security_rule       SNMP RULES  SKEW SNMP RULE
>     false   accept  ;;ss01_10.32.2.20;SS02_10.32.2.61;SYS002_10.32.2.10;FKC_10.32.2.21  ;;SKEW_DMZ_10.41.7.0_24;SKEW_10.41.6.240_29 ;;snmp;snmp-trap;echo-reply;echo-request    Log DREAM_SKEW  Any 
>   NEW RULE:

The `print` results are correct and i am expecting to see the same in file.Why would `ofile.write` print only partially (the text in bold is missed by the `ofile.write` command)

I am fairly new to python and this is a part of my first usable script. How do i get the same output in ofile as `print` command?

Edit:
Full Code

```
# Objective of this program is to get input from user as one IP address, and
# - Find out which group objects they are part of (network objects are currently out of scope)
# - which rules are these host or group objects being called in

import os
import re


def buildsearhlist(sss, iof, sl):
    with open(iof, 'r') as infile:
        for i in infile:
            eachi = i.split("\t")
            if sss[0] in eachi[3]:
                sl.append([eachi[0], eachi[2], sss[0]])
                buildsearhlist([eachi[0], eachi[2]], iof, sl)


def buildruleset(sl, irf, orf):
    for a, b, c in sl:
        with open(irf, 'r') as ifile, open(orf, 'a') as ofile:
            for k in ifile:
                eachk = k.split('\t')
                if a in eachk[7] or a in eachk[8]:
                    print(k)
                    ofile.write(k)


def rulebasefiles(rbf):
    for i in os.listdir('rulebase'):
        if re.search('rulebase.tsv', i):
            rulebase_files.append(i)
    return rbf


# ipaddr = input('Which IP do you want to search? ')
# addrtype = input('Enter the type of object (host/network/group) Only 'host' supported at the moment: ')
ipaddr = '10.32.2.20'
addrtype = 'host'


starterset = [ipaddr, addrtype]
objfile = 'rulebase\\Objects.tsv'
searchlist = []
rulebase_files = []

buildsearhlist(starterset, objfile, searchlist)
rulebase_files = rulebasefiles(rulebase_files)

# print(searchlist)

for i in rulebase_files:
    targetfilename = ipaddr + "_" + re.search('^([\w\W]*)_rulebase.tsv', i).group(1) + "rules.tsv"
    with open('rulebase\\target\\'+targetfilename, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write("Rule no.\tAdminInfo\theader text\theader rule name\tname\tdisabled\taction\tsrc\tdst\tservices\ttrack\tinstall\tthrough\tcomments\n")
        buildruleset(searchlist, 'rulebase\\'+i, 'rulebase\\target\\'+targetfilename)
```

Comment: Please put up the full code for full and better understanding

Comment: @mahir Pasted full code in original post

Comment: @njathan: Don't use `with open(...` inside a `loop`, her `for a, b, c in sl:`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint @stovfl.
I decreased the intend on the following code and it resolved the issue

```
buildruleset(searchlist, 'rulebase\\'+i, 'rulebase\\target\\'+targetfilename)
```

Also in line with your recommendation, i am now explicitly using "close" before i enter a loop to avoid this problem (see example below)

```
            for m in [7, 8, 9]:
                for k in eachj[m].split(';'):
                    objecttree(k, objfile, targetfile_e)
                ofile = open(targetrulepath_expanded+i+'.csv', 'a')
                ofile.write("\",\"")
                ofile.close()  # coz module 'objecttree' has a 'with open' statement within
            ofile = open(targetrulepath_expanded+i+'.csv', 'a')
            ofile.write(eachj[11]+"\"\n")
```

. Is there any other best practice?